# how to patch android studio form 1.0.1 to 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio 1.0.1 and want to update to 1.3, the 'Update and Restart' button didn't appear only 'download', so I downloaded the patch file from this [Latest Android Studio Canary Build: 1.3 Preview 1](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/)
downloaded .zip file Windows version. how can I patch it using that .zip file ?

Comment: What is size of file you downloaded?

Comment: File size is: 272.721 KB
Title: android-studio-ide-141.1962279-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace your old Android Studio folder's with the content of zip downloaded. Just be careful about tree view.

That's what I did, and it works.

Comment: Corrupted my android studio and I had to reinstall.
1. import all the settings first I guess, I cant even try now.